# PHP - dúvidas com date("Y-m-d")

Tags: php, foreach

Boa tarde pessoa, alguém poderia me auxiliar em uma duvida.
Eu tenho esse foreach que percorre um array e verifica se a DATA ATUAL é igual a $value['Conta']['data_vencimento']
Se for ele encaminha um SMS informando que a conta vai vencer.

```
foreach ($contasVencida as $key => $value) {
if (date("Y-m-d") == $value['Conta']['data_vencimento'] && !isset($_COOKIE['send_sms_Vayron'])){

    //Faz envio do SMS
    echo $this->element('NexmoMessage');
```

Minha dúvida seria 
Eu gostaria de **não avisar a pessoa no dia** e SIM **um dia antes** ou seja date("Y-m-d") -1 Dia

Ou seja teria que tirar -1day do $value['Conta']['data_vencimento']
porque ai eu fazia se a data atual for igual a conta vencimento -1Day

**para que o disparo do SMS seja ocorrido um dia antes da conta vencer.**
conta vence 19/03 o sms disparava no dia 18/03

Comment: dá uma olhada nesse link, talvez possa ajudar de alguma maneira: https://celke.com.br/artigo/adicionar-e-subtrair-data-em-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A forma como está fazendo não é o ideal. A cada loop uma nova data é gerada, porém, como você está trabalhando apenas com dia, mês e ano, dificilmente a última data será diferente da primeira (só se você executar o script alguns milisegundos antes de virar o dia). É melhor criar a data antes e sempre usar a mesma variável

Pra isso você pode usar a API [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php), os objetos criados a partir dela possuem o método `sub` que permite reduzir a data em um determinado período, no caso, o `P`eríodo de `1` (um) `D`ia (`'P1D'`). Depois basta usar o método `format` para retornar uma string com o formato específicado

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime();

$date->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));

$date = $date->format('Y-m-d');

foreach ($contasVencida as $key => $value) {
    if ($date == $value['Conta']['data_vencimento'] && !isset($_COOKIE['send_sms_Vayron'])){
        //Faz envio do SMS
        echo $this->element('NexmoMessage');

        // ...
```

Comment: é isso mesmo deu certo obrigado]

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime`:

```php
date("Y-m-d", strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($date_raw)))
```

Pode usar a mesma lógica (só que com `-1 day`) pra subtrair da data_vencimento ao invés de somar a data atual.

Comment: Então eu achei essa solução tmb mais olha o debug de como vem a data:
\app\View\Dashboards\index.ctp (line 239)
$value['Conta']['data_vencimento']  = '2020-03-20'

Ao passar o date $dataFormatada = strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($value['Conta']['data_vencimento']));
\app\View\Dashboards\index.ctp (line 239)
Debug: (int) 1584586800

Comment: A sintaxe está errada

Comment: Qual seria o jeito correto?

Comment: Já consegui fazer utilizando do tutorial de cima obrigado amigo